# How to handle transitive (NuGet) references in the full .NET framework?

Tags: msbuild, nuget

*I'm pretty sure the question is answered somewhere else, but my Google is not working.*

I have a `ConsoleApp` and a `ClassLib` projects in my solution. `ClassLib` references and uses `UltimateProblemSolver` assembly which was installed via NuGet. `ConsoleApp` references `ClassLib`, but not `UltimateProblemSolver`.

In `ConsoleApp` I'm calling a method from `ClassLib` which uses `UltimateProblemSolver`. I'll get a runtime exception unless I install `UltimateProblemSolver` into `ConsoleApp`.

What am I doing wrong here? Am I supposed to manually install all the NuGet packages required by the library into any app that uses it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using packages.config, then you need to install the NuGet Package into the console application as well.

If you are using the [newer PackageReference format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files) where the references are part of the .csproj file, then NuGet will handle transitive references for you.

Visual Studio can also migrate your projects from packages.config to PackageReference. See its [migration documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference).